# ng-multiselect-dropdown - 'IDropdownSettings' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use [`ng-multiselect-dropdown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown) in my angular app.

I am getting this error is VSCode when I am defining the settings:

> 'IDropdownSettings' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

I have imported the module using `npm i ng-multiselect-dropdown` and I have defined in `app.module.ts`. I was following the guide [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown).

I this how my settings look in my `page.component.ts`:

```
import { IDropdownSettings } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown'

export class VQCComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdownSettings = {};

  ngOnInit() {
     this.dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings = {
        singleSelection: false,
        idField: 'item_id',
        textField: 'item_text',
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        unSelectAllText: 'Unselect All',
        itemsShowLimit: 3,
        allowSeachFilter: true
     }
  }
}
```

The error is being highlighted on this line:

```
    this.dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings = {
```

What is causing this error? I have followed the guide, and I cannot seem to find any other documentation on this module.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

typing a variable is only possible at declaration:

```
export class VQCComponent implements OnInit {
  dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.dropdownSettings = {
        singleSelection: false,
        idField: 'item_id',
        textField: 'item_text',
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        unSelectAllText: 'Unselect All',
        itemsShowLimit: 3,
        allowSeachFilter: true
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant that has resolved it. Any reason why in the guide it has `this.dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings {}`? Would it have been possible in previous version of angular?

Comment: @JackU to answer that long-hanging comment: not possible, must be a typo in the guide

Comment: Assigning an empty object worked for me..  `dropdownSettings:IDropdownSettings = {};`